# How to search a String for characters and replace those characters with new ones?

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I want to go through an ArrayList within a for loop 
and check if a String contains a character `A`

i.e.:

```
String = "A"
```

and replace that character with (say) the characters `A&%`
so that now,

```
String = "A&%"
```

and going through again, it sees another `A`
so now it should be

```
String = "A&%&%"
```

so in a sense it's a rule: 
replace all `A` occurrences with `A&%`

```
  ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();

   myList.add("A");
   for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++){

       if(myList.contains('A')){
           myList.add("A&%");
       }
       System.out.println(myList);
   }
```

Comment: Why not just `String.replace()`?

Comment: You can't change a list when looping through it

Comment: `myList.contains('A')` would return false for a `List<String>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want it to go through the ArrayList with a for loop and check if the String contains a character 'A'

You need to use `get(i)` because you want to check the string contains, not the list contains.

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++){
    if(myList.get(i).contains("A")) {
```

> and replace that character with say characters A&%

You need to update the string in the list, not add to the list

```
        myList.set(i, myList.get(i).replace("A", "A&%"));
    }
}   
System.out.println(myList);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to ask, but I answered the initial question to the best of my knowledge, so not clear why I got downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

You should use this piece of code instead:

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add("A");
for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
    String s = myList.get(i);
    if (s.contains("A")) {
        s = s.replace("A", "A&%");
        myList.set(i, s);
    }
    System.out.println(myList);
}
```